# Shutdown seems to freeze my cpu on dell latitude e7470 under arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, shutdown, laptop

I bought a Dell Latitude e7470 recently. I immediately removed the preinstalled Windows 10, and installed Arch Linux.

It works fine, except for one thing: On shutdown or reboot, at the point where the pc would usually switch off (all processes ended, etc.), the laptop just hangs for around 30-60 secs. While it hangs, the battery led flickers in a pattern that, according to Dell's owners manual, signals "CPU failure". After the 30-60 secs, the fan spins up to max rpm, and then the system crashes (just shuts off, doesn't reboot until I press the power button again).

I suspect that somehow, the linux kernel issues the wrong shutdown command to the cpu, but I have very little knowledge on how to figure this out. Can anyone give me any tips on this? The cpu is an i-5 6300.

```
journalctl -p err
```

gives me

```
-- Reboot --
Jan 07 21:11:13 gaspodelaptop systemd-udevd[207]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event9' (scan code 0x150, key code 190): Invalid argument
Jan 07 21:11:13 gaspodelaptop kernel: dell_laptop: Setting old previous keyboard state failed
Jan 07 21:11:14 gaspodelaptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
Jan 08 01:49:19 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:19 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:19 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:19 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:19 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:20 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:20 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:20 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:20 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:20 gaspodelaptop gnome-session-binary[569]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 08 01:49:22 gaspodelaptop gdm[357]: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
-- Reboot --
```

Output of `dmesg | grep microcode`:

```
[    0.878621] microcode: sig=0x406e3, pf=0x80, revision=0x9e
[    0.878759] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

UPDATE: It seems to be a kernel issue. After investigating my suspicion of the SSD, I stumbled upon [this](https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=8mk1544huj730kqeplg9biha70&topic=6429.0) forum post. In there it is mentioned that it's a kernel Bug that is already being fixed. According to [this Bugreport](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187061), it's going to be fixed in Kernel 4.9-rc7. I guess i will have to wait a while, but since I am on Arch Linux, it shouldn't take too long. I know I could also compile my own kernel, but I'm too lazy (or better: too busy with other things) for that. Guess I'll just use standby a lot.

Comment: Assuming that this happens on Linux, you can try pressing F12 just after shutdown procedure starts. This will give you a verbose output on what's happening in the background.

Comment: @MayankVerma I did, and the last thing it says is something like "Exception:Emask" but it is only there for half a second so I cannot read the rest

Comment: And also something about bluetooth firmware that could not be loaded, but that shouldn't cause the shutdown process to crash, should it. Why is it loading firmware at shutdown anyways

Comment: Can you post your errors from `journalctl -p err` ?

Comment: I can. The problem is, that my journalctl does not output everything due to ratelimiting, and the options "RateLimitIntervalSec" and "RateLimitBurst" seem to be ignored...

Comment: During the shut down, do you see the message "reached shutdown target" before it hangs?  Since you said "all processes ended, etc." I'm guessing you do.  If not, what is the last service or target shutdown message you see?

Comment: I received my Dell Mobile Precision 7510 today, which is unfortunately quite different from your Dell.  Nonetheless, I too have removed the pre-installed OS (ubuntu) and am in the process of installing Arch.  Let me know if there is anything you did during the install that was not according to the manual, or if you are using encryption, or any non-standard configurations, etc., etc., and I'll try to reproduce.  Regardless of course I'll let you know if I experience anything similar to your problem.

Comment: I did nothing special, I followed the installation guide. However, since your Dell came with ubuntu, I guess they already provided linux drivers, which are now probably integrated into the kernel...

Comment: I do see "Reached shutdown target" Immediately afterwards, it says some intel firmware for bluetooth couldn't be loaded. about 30 secs after that, the fan spins up and some error message is shown just for a tenth of a sec before it shuts down. I'll try blacklisting bluetooth to see if it helps

Comment: I blacklisted bluetooth and it did make the bluetooth exception vanish, but didn't change anything about the behaviour otherwise. As I've seen the error message a few more times, I think I could make out something about ata. I will try and play around with hard drive settings in the BIOS

Comment: So I got Arch installed on my Dell Mobile Precision 7510.  I installed _intel_ucode_ and included that in my boot entry config file (using systemd boot, not grub).  When I shut down with _systemctl halt_ it appears to go through the shutdown  process normally up to reaching the _shutdown target_, then never shuts down.  However, there is no problem with _systemctl reboot_, so I don't think we quite have the same issue here. Unfortunately I will not be able so look at this more until later today but I'll let you know if I discover anything useful for you.

Comment: As far as my Dell coming with Ubuntu pre-installed:  As I say, I wiped it out to install Arch, and my system came with no driver or install media.  The advantage in my mind of it coming with a GNU-Linux OS pre-loaded is that means all the hardware should be supported by the Linux kernel.  I did boot up Ubuntu a couple times and would do a full shutdown from its GUI interface in about 1-2 seconds.

Comment: It's a kernel bug, see my update to the question. Since your Laptop ships with Linux, they (Dell and the other Hardware manufacturers) have themselves written drivers for linux and integrated them into the kernel. So any Linux will work on your machine, since the drivers are in the kernel...

Answer (score 2):

Install the `intel-ucode` package!

Processor manufacturers release stability and security updates to the processor microcode. While microcode can be updated through the BIOS, the Linux kernel is also able to apply these updates during boot. These updates provide bug fixes that can be critical to the stability of your system. Without these updates, you may experience spurious crashes or unexpected system halts that can be difficult to track down.
Users of CPUs belonging to the Intel Haswell and Broadwell processor families in particular must install these microcode updates to ensure system stability. But all Intel users should install the updates as a matter of course.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode

Comment: I did that during the installation. I added a second initrd line (the ucode line first) as described in the article you linked. However, I am experiencing some issues with systemd-boot, so is there any way I can verify that the microcode is loaded?

Comment: dmesg | grep microcode

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode#Verifying_that_microcode_got_updated_on_boot

Comment: Thank you, I will check tonight. I am currently at work and don't have the laptop with me.

Comment: Looks like microcode is loaded, I added the output of dmesg to the  question

Comment: Ok I verified that the loaded microcode is the correct one for my cpu. I have also installed the latest BIOS update before changing to linux.

Comment: You mentioned Dell's Owner manual said Signal's CPU failure.Did you check with Dell Tech Support? Why did you update BIOS with latest version? Any problem with previous BIOS?

Comment: It said that I should update somewhere on the Dell Page, I think there was an issue with the first bios, I don't remember what it was about. I will contact Dell Support, but since there is no Linux support for my model, I guess they will just say "If it works under Windows, it's not our cup of tea!"